# Cannot import Kmeans anymore

Tags: python-3.x, scikit-learn, k-means

I tried to import `Kmeans`

```
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
```

And I got this error :

```
AttributeError: module 'sklearn.utils._openmp_helpers' has no attribute '__pyx_capi__'
```

Never had this problem before and that's not the first time I use `Kmeans`.

I tried to uninstall sklearn and install it again, but that doesn't change anything.

I have the last version of sklearn, if it could help :

```
import sklearn
sklearn.__version__

'0.24.1'
```

EDIT : Here's the full error, if you want details :

```
----> 1 from sklearn.cluster import KMeans

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\cluster\__init__.py in <module>
      4 """
      5 
----> 6 from ._spectral import spectral_clustering, SpectralClustering
      7 from ._mean_shift import mean_shift, MeanShift, estimate_bandwidth, get_bin_seeds
      8 from ._affinity_propagation import affinity_propagation, AffinityPropagation

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\cluster\_spectral.py in <module>
     17 from ..base import BaseEstimator, ClusterMixin
     18 from ..utils import check_random_state, as_float_array, check_scalar
---> 19 from ..metrics.pairwise import pairwise_kernels
     20 from ..neighbors import kneighbors_graph, NearestNeighbors
     21 from ..manifold import spectral_embedding

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\metrics\__init__.py in <module>
     39 from ._dist_metrics import DistanceMetric
     40 
---> 41 from . import cluster
     42 from .cluster import adjusted_mutual_info_score
     43 from .cluster import adjusted_rand_score

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\metrics\cluster\__init__.py in <module>
     20 from ._supervised import fowlkes_mallows_score
     21 from ._supervised import entropy
---> 22 from ._unsupervised import silhouette_samples
     23 from ._unsupervised import silhouette_score
     24 from ._unsupervised import calinski_harabasz_score

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\metrics\cluster\_unsupervised.py in <module>
     14 from ...utils import check_X_y
     15 from ...utils import _safe_indexing
---> 16 from ..pairwise import pairwise_distances_chunked
     17 from ..pairwise import pairwise_distances
     18 from ...preprocessing import LabelEncoder

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\metrics\pairwise.py in <module>
     31 from ..utils.fixes import sp_version, parse_version
     32 
---> 33 from ._pairwise_distances_reduction import PairwiseDistancesArgKmin
     34 from ._pairwise_fast import _chi2_kernel_fast, _sparse_manhattan
     35 from ..exceptions import DataConversionWarning

sklearn\metrics\_pairwise_distances_reduction.pyx in init sklearn.metrics._pairwise_distances_reduction()

AttributeError: module 'sklearn.utils._openmp_helpers' has no attribute '__pyx_capi__'
```